# Extract Title of a html file using grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

```
cat 1.html | grep "<title>" > title.txt
```

This grep statement is not working.

Please tell the best way to grab the title of a page using grep or sed.

Thanks.

Comment: [Friends don't let friends parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (stolen from [Ether](http://stackoverflow.com/users/40468/ether)).

Comment: his requirement is very simple. Regular expression is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use awk. This works even for multiline

```
$ cat file

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <title>Extract Title of a html file

using grep - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=9ea1a272f146">

$ awk -vRS="</title>" '/<title>/{gsub(/.*<title>|\n+/,"");print;exit}' file
Extract Title of a html file using grep - Stack Overflow
```

Comment: Hey GhostDog74, I created a follow up question to this so the awk command would operate on several lines not just one, if you could give your input at all, that would be great - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650612/how-to-extract-text-between-html-tags-with-or-condition-multiple-times

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n 's/<title>\(.*\)<\/title>/\1/Ip' 1.html
```

uses the combination of -n and p to only print matches

Comment: This assumes that nothing else appears on the line containing `<title>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use xml_grep from the [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.35/Twig.pm) Perl package:

```
xml_grep --text_only title 1.html
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat 1.html | grep -oE "<title>.*</title>" | sed 's/<title>//' | sed 's/<\/title>//'
```

Grep with -oE extract only the title tag, then sed remove the html tags

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep "<title>" /path/to/html.html
```

Works fine for me. Are you sure 1.html is in your current working directory? `pwd` to check.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Hovansky's answer is good enough, although there is a chance that html is not well formed and your xml_grep would crash

I recommend use tidy to convert html to xml, then use xml_grep

```
tidy -asxml -utf8 html_file.html > out.xml
xml_grep 'xpath_expression' out.xml
```