# How to match content between HTML specific tags with attribute using grep?

Tags: regex, grep, html-parsing

Which regular expression should I use with the command *grep* if I wanted to match the text contained within the tag `<div class="Message">` and its closing tag `</div>` in an HTML file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<div class="Message"> ).*?(?= </div>)' file
```

If your tags span multiple lines, try:

```
< file tr -d '\n' | grep -oP '(?<=<div class="Message"> ).*?(?= </div>)'
```

Comment: One has to assume that the tags can span multiple lines.

Comment: What does the "?<=" mean in front of <div class?

Comment: @InquilineKea: It's (part of) a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: `tr -d '\r\n'` for windows line breaks

Comment: Hi guys, I' was unable to make this code work. Can you see why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866839/how-to-match-content-between-tags-without-regex

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: That's just because your tags span multiple lines. The easiest thing to do is to just remove them first. Please see again the above.

Comment: `grep -P` works on Linux and some other platforms, but is not portable. If you have Perl ..   but then if you have Perl you also have easy access to a proper HTML parser.

Comment: But how to do this if I have multiple classes in my element and I want to check just one of them?

Comment: @mohsinali1317 I think at that point it'd just be easier with Perl or Python or some other tool that can parse HTML. And more robust too.

Comment: I tried this tr '\n' ' ' < input_file | grep -E "^<div class=\".* Message\">.*</div>$"
but didn't wokred. don't have the option to use anything else @Steve

Comment: @mohsinali1317 Well, you've translated away all of your new line characters so now you're just matching the start and end of your line. You might get some output if you drop the line anchors. Or, you might need to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by specifying a regex:

```
grep -E "^<div class=\"Message\">.*</div>$" input_files
```

Not that this will only print the enclosures found on the same line. If your tag spans multiple lines, you can try:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input_file | grep -E "^<div class=\"Message\">.*</div>$"
```

Comment: thanks for the answers. My tags span multiple lines, when I run your command I obtain this error: tr: extra operand `test.txt'
Try `tr --help' for more information.

Comment: @Albz: Try, `tr '\n' ' ' < test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it reliably with just grep.  You need to parse the HTML with an HTML parser.

What if the HTML code has something like:

```
<!--
<div class="Message">blah blah</div>
-->
```

You'll get a false hit on that commented-out code.  Here are some [other examples](http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html) where a regex-only option will fail you.

Consider using xmlgrep from the `XML::Grep` Perl module, as discussed here: [Extract Title of a html file using grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833088/extract-title-of-a-html-file-using-grep)

Comment: +1 Thats a good idea. I didn't consider commented code, but I'm not convinced the OP has either.