# Get content between HTML Tags | Special Character Meaning?

Tags: html, regex, bash, grep, character

Before someone marks this as duplicate, I want to remark that I have seen posts like this one:
[HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566574/how-to-match-content-between-html-specific-tags-with-attribute-using-grep)

Sadly, the solution there doesn't work for me.

After a very helpful comment, I realize now that my initial problem was not getting the text between HTML tags, but using greps with non ASCII characters. This question therefore seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix). Thanks for all the helpful comments, and sorry for the duplication, I honestly googled for an hour before posting here!

I think the character " ’ " is the problem, because grep -E -o '().*' only matches up to this character. I am not sure why that is, and would appreciate any help or hints on this.

The problem is as follows: I have a file, that for example looks like this, and I want to extract the text between the strong tags:

```
> <p>Here is something</p> <ul>   <li>
>     <p><strong>Here is something else</strong> And I keep typing here
```

The strongs are always in the same line, which should make it easier, at least I think so.

My own thoughts led me to

`grep -E -o '\<strong\>.*\<\/strong\>' test.txt`

Until I realized \< only looks for the beginning of a word (I wasn't sure < had a special meaning so I wanted to escape it).

I then went on to try `grep -E -o '(<strong>).*(<\/strong>)` which, amazingly, works for the test file I gave you above.

Now, the truth is, the original file has book titles between the strong Tags, and book titles tend to contain apostrophes, and I think they mess things up. 
Let's look at another sample file:

```
> <p>Here is something</p> <ul>   <li>
> <p><strong>That`s a stupid</strong> And I keep typing here <p>>
> <strong>Complications: A Surgeon’s Notes on an Imperfect Science</strong> ?
> blablabla <p><strong>Another test, with this kind of ' apostrophe</strong> bla bla
```

Now using the grep from before `grep -E -o '(<strong>).*(<\/strong>)'` Only returns the first and third match:

```
> <strong>That`s a stupid</strong> 
> <strong>Another test, with this kind of ' apostroph</strong>
```

I don't understand why

```
 "<strong>Complications: A Surgeon’s Notes on an Imperfect Science</strong>"
```

isn't matched. 
I am prety sure the character " ’ " is the problem, because `grep -E -o '(<strong>).*'` only matches "Complications: A Surgeon".
Any ideas on why the character " ’ " would make any problems? I noticed that when printing the file cat file.txt the character is also displayed incorrectly.

Also, on a similar note: Right now grep is still returning the  tags. How do I disable this? I think there's just an argument I can use there (that's why I included the parentheses in my code), but I can't seem to find it.

Thank you all, any help is appreciated! 
I am also very sorry for the bad formatting, I think the HTML tags in the example files spilled over into the question...

Comment: `’` is a different character than the normal apostrophe `'`, so `.` not matching that character could be the reason. Maybe some charset expert can shed more light on this. I would try to reword the question/title to avoid it being closed.

Comment: And in case you are wondering, I just noticed you have already found out most of this. I hadn't read your last paragraph before.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did change the title and added a first paragraph. Is there any thing I cal change about my RegExp that would avoid the problem? For example, ignore non standard characters? Or should I in a first step just replace all of these strange apostrophes by "normal" ones? How would one do that, if I can t find them with a regexp?

Comment: It's actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix

Comment: Okay, that looks like it might solve my problem after some more googling. Thanks!

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ