# Auto-generate title from filename in Pelican

Tags: python, jinja2, regex-group, python-re, pelican

### 1. Summary

I can’t automatically generate the correct `title` from filenames of articles/pages.

For example, I can’t automatically generate [**metadata key `title`**](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/content.html#file-metadata) `Kira Goddess` from article `Kira-Goddess.md`

### 2. Argumentation

[**DRY**](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/97-things-every/9780596809515/ch30.html), automation. I don’t want to manually write the title every time for each article and page if I can do it automatically.

An exception — files with words, that contain hyphens — “well-known”, “English-speaking”. In this case, I must explicitly specify `title` in the metadata of my articles. But words with hyphens are rare in filenames of my articles.

### 3. MCVE

#### 3.1. Data

You can see it in my [**`KiraTitleFromFilename` branch**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPelicanDebugging/tree/KiraTitleFromFilename) of my repository for Pelican debugging.

- `pelicanconf.py`:

  ```py
  """MCVE."""

  AUTHOR = 'Sasha Chernykh'
  SITENAME = 'SashaPelicanDebugging'
  SITEURL = '.'

  PATH = 'content'

  TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

  DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'

  # [INFO] Use article name when preserve the slug:
  # https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#url-settings
  SLUGIFY_SOURCE = 'basename'

  # [INFO] Preserve case of article filename
  SLUGIFY_PRESERVE_CASE = True

  # [INFO] Get title from article filename:
  # https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#metadata
  # https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/2107
  # https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/commit/2e82a53cdf3f1f9d66557850cc2811479d5bb645
  FILENAME_METADATA = '(?P<title>.*)'
  ```
- `Kira-Goddess.md`:

  ```
  Date: 2020-09-24 18:57:33

  Kira Goddess!
  ```

Another Pelican files generated by [**pelican-quickstart**](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/quickstart.html#create-a-project).

Simplified part of `base.html`:

```
<title>{{ article.title }}</title>
```

#### 3.2. Steps to reproduce

See [**`.travis.yml`**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPelicanDebugging/blob/c5b15eb99116fa73fb2cb8a0d57be572e90c155b/.travis.yml):

1. Run Pelican build:

   ```
   pelican content -s pelicanconf.py --fatal warnings --verbose
   ```
2. [**Finding content of `<title>` tag**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566657/5951529):

   ```
   grep -E "<title>.*</title>" output/Kira-Goddess.html
   ```

#### 3.3. Behavior

3.3.1. Current

See [**Travis build**](https://travis-ci.org/github/Kristinita/SashaPelicanDebugging/builds/730045993#L285):

```html
<title>Kira-Goddess</title>
```

3.3.2. Desired

It would be nice, if:

```
<title>{{ article.title }}</title>
```

will transform to:

```html
<title>Kira Goddess</title>
```

### 4. Not helped

In the [**description of `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA`**](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/4.5.0/settings.html#metadata) variable I read, that Pelican used [**Python group name notation**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) syntax `(?P<name>…)`. I couldn’t find, how I can make substitutions in Python `<class 'str'>` (`print(type(FILENAME_METADATA))` → `<class 'str'>`). I tried variants as:

```py
import re

KIRA_DEFAULT_FILENAME_REGEX = '(?P<title>.*)'
FILENAME_METADATA = re.sub(KIRA_DEFAULT_FILENAME_REGEX, "-", " ")
```

or

```py
KIRA_DEFAULT_FILENAME_REGEX = '(?P<title>.*)'
FILENAME_METADATA = KIRA_DEFAULT_FILENAME_REGEX.replace("-", "")
```

It doesn’t work.

### 5. Don’t offer

#### 5.1. Use Jinja2 filters in templates

5.1.1. Suggestion

[**Use `replace()` filter**](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#replace) in your template files like this:

```
<title>{{ article.title|replace('-', " ") }}</title>
```

5.1.2. Why is it not good

Pelican plugins (e.g. [**Pelican Open Graph**](https://github.com/whiskyechobravo/pelican-open_graph)) still will use `article.title`. Unwanted data as `Kira-Goddess`, not `Kira Goddess` still will pass to plugins.

#### 5.2. Use spaces in your Markdown

5.2.1. Suggestion

For example, name your file `Kira Goddess.md`, not `Kira-Goddess.md`.

5.2.2. Why is it not good

Whitespaces in filenames is a bad practice — [**1**](https://superuser.com/q/29111/572069), [**2**](https://portal.slac.stanford.edu/sites/inc_public/Pages/folder-file-names.aspx), [**3**](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1kpzxz/what_are_your_file_naming_conventions/), [**4**](https://www2.le.ac.uk/services/research-data/organise-data/naming-files), [**5**](https://library.stanford.edu/research/data-management-services/data-best-practices/best-practices-file-naming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to write a (small) plugin for Pelican. You probably want to hook up to the `article_generator_context` (and/or `page_generator_context`) signal. Your plugin would be passed the metadata table for the article, and you could do the substitution there. Something like this (untested):

```py
"""
Pelican plugin to replace "-" with a space in an article's title.
"""

from pelican import signals

def title_replace(generator, metadata):
    try:
        metadata["title"] = metadata["title"].replace("-", " ")
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # not sure if you have to return metadata, or if it is
    # globally updated as it's a dictionary
    return metadata


def register():
    """Register the plugin pieces with Pelican."""

    signals.article_generator_context.connect(title_replace)
    signals.page_generator_context.connect(title_replace)
```

Don't forget to add this your your list of plugins in your `pelicanconf.py`.

More on [Pelican Plugins](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/plugins.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer! This plugin doesn’t work as expected if hyphenated words required in the title. For example, if I manually add the title to my article metadata — `Title: Kira-my-title-with-hyphenated-words`, plugin transform this title to `Kira my title with hyphenated words`.
Is there any way to realize the behavior I described below? 1) If no `Title` key in the article/page metadata, plugin replaces `-` to the space, 2) But else user manually add key `Title` to the article/page metadata, the plugin will not perform any operations on the value of this key. Thanks.

Comment: I’ve looked at the sources of other plugins on GitHub, and I still don’t understand what I have to do to implement the behavior I described in the previous comment. I modified the plugin so that the desired behavior could be achieved by an additional key (`PreserveTitle`) in the metadata of an article/page whose title the plugin shouldn’t change. [**Modified plugin on Gist**](https://gist.github.com/Kristinita/da80bdb435e6617878af5f509cd1fee7). Perhaps there is some way without extra key. Thanks.

Comment: What about publishing the plugin? I think many Pelican users would like to avoid manually adding a title to each article/page. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! To keep hyphens in certain titles, you'd have to (probably) either have a whitelist of "hypenated words" or have another metadata key, either like you've done with `PreseveTitle` or add a `raw_title` key that will overwrite whatever is showing as `title`. The deeper issue is that the plugin doesn't really have a way of knowing what the "original" title was, only what it is currently.

Comment: As for publishing this, it's hard to reason about how to do this as generically; it seems that most implementations would be very tied to the site using it. Plus I wouldn't be using it, which makes it hard for me to make sure it keeps working as its supposed to. But please feel free to publish it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `pelican` doesn't provide a way to implement what you want.
`FILENAME_METADATA` regex can only select a name from a filename, but you can't substitute `-` with whitespaces there.

So I think the current best way for you is to specify `title` tag manually in each file.