# How To Extract Text Between HTML Tags With Or Condition Multiple Times

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have been researching how to extract title tags from html. I've pretty much figured out that regex and html don't mix and that grep can be used. However, the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833088/extract-title-of-a-html-file-using-grep), looks like this:

```
awk -vRS="</title>" '/<title>/{gsub(/.*<title>|\n+/,"");print;exit}'
```

Now, this works to find the text between title tags only once. I would like to know how I can make it run on every line. I could do a `cat file; while read line; do ...; done`. However, I know that is probably not very efficient an there's a better way.

Secondly, in the file I need to keep any lines that start with string '--'. I believe this requires adding an 'or' statement in `awk` so that it will match the title tags and any line starting with '--'

The input file would look like this:

```
text text text <title>random text of the title 1</title> random html stuff
--time--
xyz more random text <title>random text of the title 2</title> hmtl text
--time--
some text <title>random text of the title 3</title> more text tags
--time--
text here <title>random text of the title 4</title> random text html
--time--
```

The desired output:

```
<title>random text of the title 1</title>
--time--
<title>random text of the title 2</title>
--time--
<title>random text of the title 3</title>
--time--
<title>random text of the title 4</title>
--time--
```

I'm not that great with awk, but I'm learning. I know there should be an option to print all, but it's the OR statement that I'm really stuck on. I am open to sed or grep if you think that's more efficient. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given input, `grep` is enough

```
$ grep -o '<.*>\|^--.*' ip.html 
<title>random text of the title 1</title>
--time--
<title>random text of the title 2</title>
--time--
<title>random text of the title 3</title>
--time--
<title>random text of the title 4</title>
--time--
```

- `-o` extract only matching parts
- `<.*>` extract from `<` upto last `>` in the line
- `\|^--.*` alternate pattern, if line starts with `--` get everything from that line

To restrict only to `title` tags,

```
grep -o '<title.*title>\|^--.*' ip.html
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, sorry my example is not detailed enough, but I tried to explain with my dummy text and the question title that the other lines are HTML text so the code needs to specify <title>.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured, `grep -o '<title.*title>\|^--.*'` doesn't work too? are the `title` tags spread over multiple lines? can you edit your question with sample input where this solution fails?

Comment: wow. It worked. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot.